# How can I estimate the Euclidean distance?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, estimation

I read in an article the Euclidean distance formula can be estimated with about 6% relative error with the following formula. Would you please **why** this is true and **where** can I find such estimations? Is it possible to **extend** it for higher dimensions?

$d(a,b) = \max(|a_x-b_x|,|a_y-b_y|) + 0.365 \times \min(|a_x-b_x|,|a_y-b_y|) $

The original formula in the article "SOLVING LARGE VEHICLE ROUTING AND SCHEDULING PROBLEMS IN SMALL CORE", by Bordin:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will follow the notation in the previous comment.
First, *u* itself is not a bad estimation. The maximal possible relative error with it is just $\sqrt{2}-1 < 42\% $. If it is generalized for *n* dimensions, then the error will be $\sqrt{n} - 1$, which means for higher dimensions this simple approximation won't work very well.

Now, let's imagine the unit circle, one point is in the center and an other one is running. At $0°$, $90°$, $180°$, $270°$ the formula *u* already gives a perfect result. For each running point, take the point of the corresponding radius which is as far from the center as the naive formula *u* estimates. Because of cosine, this curve lies on four symmetric Thales-circles, so the error function won't be very nice.

To improve the formula, we could try $u+(\sqrt{2}-1)*v$, because it provides perfect results at $45°$, $135°$, $225°$, $315°$ as well. The error is 
maximal at $22.5°$, it is $cos(22.5°)+(\sqrt{2}-1)*sin(22.5°)=1.0823922$.

If the formula is $u + q * v$, the error function will be $e(\alpha)=cos(\alpha)+q*sin(\alpha)$ on the proper interval. After a not very gory derivation, it seems the error is the highest at $\tan^{-1}q$ and $e(\alpha) <= S = \sqrt{1+q^{2}}$. The error is the lowest at $45°$, hence $e(\alpha) >= T = (1+q)/\sqrt{2}$. In order to keep both the highest and the lowest error values relatively low, taking $q$ where $S = 1 / T$ seems as a natural choice. After the substitutions, it boils down solving the equation $2=(1+q^2)(1+q)(1+q)$. Unfortunately the solutions are not algebraic, but the calculator tells $q=0.3392$ and using this $q$ will keep the absolute relative error under $5.5\% $.

In 3d, I'd start with something like $u\ge v\ge w, d=(\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{0})u+(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})v+(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})w$, although it would take some time figuring out the error guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u= \max(|a_x-b_x|,|a_y-b_y|)$ and $v=\min(|a_x-b_x|,|a_y-b_y|)$, then algebra shows that
$$
d(a,b)=u+r(u,v)\cdot v,\qquad r(u,v)=\frac{v}{u+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}.
$$
Why one would think that $r(u,v)\approx0.365$ always, escapes me. In fact, $r(u,v)$ can be anywhere in the interval $[0,\sqrt2-1)\approx[0,0.414)$ and $r(u,v)\approx0.365$ if and only if $v\approx0.8422\cdot u$.

Perhaps vehicle routing involves mainly points $(a,b)$ such that $v\approx0.8422\cdot u$ holds...

Comment: I can verify your fomula, but where can I find such formula (a reference or book, if any)? Would you please let me know how can extend your formula to higher dimensions?

Comment: I never met an analogue of this formula before--and you can guess from my answer that I do not value it highly (what is the point of extending to higher dimensions a formula already wrong in 2D?). Do you have an explanation for the regime $v/u\approx.8422$?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if we consider normalized distribution of nodes in 2D, and the fact that usually $i$ and $j$ are near points, we will be able to justify it